# Android aar publish to Artifacotry through TeamCity

Tags: android, teamcity, android-library, artifactory

Currently we are using TeamCity for continuous integration and I have configured my Android library to build with TeamCity. I can upload my aar to Artifactory manualy by executing **gradle assembleRelease artifactoryPublish** command.

Is it possible to publish my library aar file to Artifactory repository from the TeamCity?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have builds running on TeamCity:

On TeamCity go to your `Project Settings` then `Build Configurations`, Select the build configuration that runs when ever TeamCity runs.
[image: Build configurations]

- Inside that `Build Configuration` select `Build Step: Gradle`, then click the `Add Build Step` Button.
- Select `Gradle` from the drop down menu.
- Give it sensible name e.g. "Publish artifact"
- Add your task names in:[image: Gradle Tasks]
- Click `Save`

Then run your TeamCity build like you usually would.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity runs Gradle tasks. Just use the `assembleRelease artifactoryPublish` tasks in TeamCity.

Comment: Thanks. I used this command in Android studio terminal and its uploaded successfully. But how can I execute this command in TeamCity?

Comment: When you configure TeamCity to work with Gradle you'll provide the list of tasks.